# Wordpress Javascript Variable Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm a Javascript beginner. I'm trying to use jQuery Cycle with Wordpress, but it doesn't seem to be working. There is no slideshow, but all the images show on. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong with setting up variables. Or, maybe it has to do with this Javascript error that I'm getting? "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }." But there's nothing where in the line where it says there is }. I'd appreciate your help!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var slideshowContainer = '.slideshow';                  // refernece of the element for the slideshow
var slideshowFx = 'fade';                               // slideshow transition type
var slideshowDelay = 2000;                              // slideshow delay
var slideshowTimeout = 0;                               // slideshow timeout
var slideshowSpeed = 500;                               // slideshow transition speed
var slideshowPadding = 130;                             // slideshow padding
var slideshowPaddingTop = 20;                           // slideshow paddingTop
var slideshowPaddingRight = 65;                         // slideshow paddingRight
var slideshowPaddingBottom = 20;                        // slideshow paddingBottom
var slideshowPaddingLeft = 65;                          // slideshow paddingLeft
var slideshowPaginator = '.slideshow_pag';              // slideshow paginator
var slideshowSeparator = '/';                           // slideshow paginator separator
var slideshowNextBtn = '.slideshow_next';               // slideshow next button
var slideshowPrevBtn = '.slideshow_prev';               // slideshow prev button
var slideshowShareLink = 'a.slideshow_share_link';      // slideshow share link
var slideshowShareContainer = '.slideshow_share';       // slideshow share container
var slideshowPreloader = '/imgs/blank.gif';         // slideshow preloader image reference

$(function() {

$('slideshowContainer').cycle({
    fx: slideshowFx,
    delay: slideshowDelay,
    speed: slideshowSpeed,
    timeout: slideshowTimeout,
    containerResize: 0,
    startingSlide: startingSlide,
    fit: 0,
    slideResize: 0,
    height: _h,
    width: _w,
    cleartype: true,
    cleartypeNoBg: true,
    next: slideshowNextBtn,
    prev: slideshowPrevBtn,
    before: function(curr, next, opts) {
        $(slideshowShareLink).removeClass('sel');
        $(slideshowShareContainer).css({'visibility':'hidden'});
        preLoadImage(opts.currSlide, opts.slideCount);
        $('.slideshow_title').html($(next).data('title'));
    },
    after: function(curr,next,opts) {
        onAfter(curr,next,opts);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var slideshowContainer = '.slideshow';                  // refernece of the element for the slideshow
    var slideshowFx = 'fade';                               // slideshow transition type
    var slideshowDelay = 2000;                              // slideshow delay
    var slideshowTimeout = 0;                               // slideshow timeout
    var slideshowSpeed = 500;                               // slideshow transition speed
    var slideshowPadding = 130;                             // slideshow padding
    var slideshowPaddingTop = 20;                           // slideshow paddingTop
    var slideshowPaddingRight = 65;                         // slideshow paddingRight
    var slideshowPaddingBottom = 20;                        // slideshow paddingBottom
    var slideshowPaddingLeft = 65;                          // slideshow paddingLeft
    var slideshowPaginator = '.slideshow_pag';              // slideshow paginator
    var slideshowSeparator = '/';                           // slideshow paginator separator
    var slideshowNextBtn = '.slideshow_next';               // slideshow next button
    var slideshowPrevBtn = '.slideshow_prev';               // slideshow prev button
    var slideshowShareLink = 'a.slideshow_share_link';      // slideshow share link
    var slideshowShareContainer = '.slideshow_share';       // slideshow share container
    var slideshowPreloader = '/imgs/blank.gif';         // slideshow preloader image reference

    // The following statement has been already defined in the top: 
    // $(function() {

    $('slideshowContainer').cycle({
        fx: slideshowFx,
        delay: slideshowDelay,
        speed: slideshowSpeed,
        timeout: slideshowTimeout,
        containerResize: 0,
        startingSlide: startingSlide,
        fit: 0,
        slideResize: 0,
        height: _h,
        width: _w,
        cleartype: true,
        cleartypeNoBg: true,
        next: slideshowNextBtn,
        prev: slideshowPrevBtn,
        before: function(curr, next, opts) {
            $(slideshowShareLink).removeClass('sel');
            $(slideshowShareContainer).css({'visibility':'hidden'});
            preLoadImage(opts.currSlide, opts.slideCount);
            $('.slideshow_title').html($(next).data('title'));
        },
        after: function(curr,next,opts) {
            onAfter(curr,next,opts);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I changed $('slideshowContainer') to $(slideshowContainer) too.